# Linkedin:recepient api request cannot be null

Tags: java, android, linkedin-j

I am trying to send an invitation, so first I look for the person using this:

`Person profile = client.getProfileById(getThirdSocial("linkedin"));`

then I get the person and I call the method：
`client.sendInviteToPerson(recepient, subject, message);`

but I get an exception:

```
1-11 11:34:40.578: W/System.err(2697): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException?: recepient api request cannot be null.
```

recepient is not null because I am able to print out some details of the person. So I do not know what to do, please help.

Comment: how do you know that? is recepient final? did you put a log befre calling sendInviteToPerson?

Comment: `client.sendInviteToPerson(profile, subject, message);`

Comment: yeah, like:
  `profile.getFirstName()`